# Ergodic process and random walk

Tags: random-walk, ergodic-theory

Is a gaussian random walk process an ergodic process? If Yes, does someone knows the proof?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, it has independent increments, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The standard random walk has no invariant distribution.  The solution is N(0,t) for $t<\infty$.  The OU process (with drift towards 0) is ergodic.